# Ubuntu 13.10 is still beta!

Tags: release-management

I wish to upgrade my current Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10. While upgrading via software updater, it popped up a window with information that "Ubuntu 13.10 is beta".

1. So, may I know when it would be beta-free?
2. As it's beta, so can it be reckoned stable or once it's free of beta then only it's stable?
3. Is it preferred or advantageous to not upgrade my system now and put off until it's beta-free?

Comment: ubuntu 13.10 stable is out for use.. download it from official website.

Comment: Did you ran `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: @Braiam I have a different query please.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `sudo apt-get update` from terminal first, and then execute `sudo do-release-upgrade`. It should update your Ubuntu to 13.10.

Comment: @rajagenupula - I've edited my answer.

Comment: I didnt downvoted your post. Just reviewed it. any how , now you posted the answer which can leads to upgrade. so +1.

Comment: That's O.K. what you wrote but I have a different query please. I have 3 questions to be answered. You have replied 'how to do' but I intend to know 'shall I do it now or put off until it's beta-free'. (addressing to @Sushantp606 also)

Comment: @Ravi To this question you were answered by user Sushantp606: Ubuntu 13.10 "Saucy Salamander" is already stable - final version was released 17.10.2013. That's why I recommended `apt-get update` - to refresh your list of available packets.